# How to add split screen ("50% image/50% text scroll box) to a full screen slide image?

Tags: html, fullpage.js

I have been trying to make a mini site template for my roleplaying users to use as their character profiles. I have decided on a slideshow sort of deal and I am using 'jquery full-page' by Ajax.

The purpose is to give users a "one page" navigated "mini-site" that they can change as often as they wish. I am hosted at Enjin, and because of this, I needed something users could access without giving everyone admin rights. With this Jquery full-page I am able to do that.

Page reads thus: 
1ST PG- Sort of landing page. (Hearth)
2ND PG- begins slide.. every page that follows is another piece of the slide.
I want to be able to add images and a text scroll box on top of the background of these slide sections.

EX. 2nd pg is the appearance pg. this page needs to show the background plus an image of the character and of course a text scroll box of the same size. So basically I need to know how to add a split screen on top of the background with the ability to hide the text scroll box until you actually scroll through the text. This last part is purely esthetic.

That's it in a nutshell. Here is my HTML:

```css
/* full width page default*/
#page{
width:100% !important;
max-width:none !important;
}

/*Remove default padding from html modules*/
.m_html{
padding:0px !important;
}


/*remove all enjin chat and tray icons*/
#enjin-tray-messaging, #enjin-tray {display: none !important;}

#enjin-tray-chatchannels {
display: none;
}
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.enjin.com/1252728/fullpage.js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.enjin.com/1252728/fullpage.js/jquery.fullPage.css">
<title>CUS PRO TEST 3</title>

<style>

#navbar {
 width:100%;
 height:30px;
 top:0px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:999;
 background-color: #000;
 opacity:0.8;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
#navbar a {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 32px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 color: #fff;
}
div img {
 width: 1600px;
 height: auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="navbar">
<a href="#page1">Hearth</a>
<a href="#page2/slide2-1">Appearence</a>
<a href="#page2/slide2-2">Personality</a>
<a href="#page2/slide2-3">History</a>
<a href="#page2/slide2-4">Journal</a>
<a href="#page2/slide2-5">Friends</a>
<a href="#page2/slide2-6">Ooc</a>
<a href="#page2/slide2-7">Courier</a>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="section" data-anchor="page1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.enjin.com/1252728/custom profiles prp/CUS PRO TEST ONE PAGE SITE/1.jpg" /></div>
 <div class="section" data-anchor="page2">
  <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.enjin.com/1252728/custom profiles prp/CUS PRO TEST ONE PAGE SITE/2.jpg"   /></div>
  <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2-2"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.enjin.com/1252728/custom profiles prp/CUS PRO TEST ONE PAGE SITE/2-2.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2-3"><img src="/images/2-3.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2-4"><img src="/images/2-4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2-5"><img src="/images/2-5.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2-6"><img src="/images/2-6.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2-7"><img src="/images/2-7.jpg" /></div>
 </div>
 </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#wrapper').fullpage({
   scrollingSpeed: 300,
   controlArrows: false
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can no one help?